# Second derivative as bilinear form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a question concerning the second derivative.
Consider the  ode $ y' = f(y)$. Then we have

$ y'' = f'(y) f(y)$

with the notation $f'(y) = f_y(y)$ beeing the derivative with respect to variable y.

Now it follows
$ y''' = f''(f,f) + f'f'f. $

How ist $(f,f)$ exactly to be understood? Is the second derivative beeing considered as a bilinearform? If yes, in which book is it well explained?

Thanks in advance for every answer.

Comment: Please specify domain and image of $y$.

Comment: domain is the set of real numbers $y(t)$, and image is $R^n$

Comment: I found the notation in this document [Runge Kutta Methods](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~frank011/Classes/numwisk/ch8.pdf) page 43-44

Comment: I think that if you look more closely you'll see that the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$. And that the book you reference defines  $(f,f)$.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the deeper meaning behind it. Would $y''' = f f'' f + f'f'f$ be wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong, because $f''$ is a vector valued bilinear form, a 3rd order tensor. You can not simply apply (inaccurate) matrix notations in a sensible way.